# Diagonal elements of a matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two $n \times n$ matrices, $Q$ and $P$, with $n > 2$. These matrices have the following properties.

1. All their elements are non-negative real numbers.
2. Their diagonal elements are zeroes.
3. All rows sum to one; combined with 1 implies that all the elements are in $[0,1]$.
4. The matrices are "sparse" i.e. some fraction $k$ of the off-diagonal elements are equal to zero.

I'm looking for additional restriction(s)/assumption(s) on $Q$ and $P$ such that the leading diagonal of $QP$ cannot equal some constant. I can find numerical examples where it is possible, and where it isn't. I suspect it has something to do with eigenvalues/diagonalization, although this is only a hunch.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean you're given a constant $\eta$ such that...what's the "leading diagonal"? The entries $A_{ii}$ with equal row and column index? And then you want to make sure not all these entries can be $\eta$? Or not any of them?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't very clear. What I'm trying to do is find a condition such that $(QP)_{ii}\neq\epsilon \text{ }\forall i$

Comment: $(QP)_{ii} \neq \epsilon$ ? Or $<\epsilon$?

Comment: $(QP)_{ii}\neq \epsilon$. I'm looking to guarantee that the diagonal elements of $QP$ are not all equal to each other.